# Twitter bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I implemented bootstrap datepicker.I want to set the default date to 30 days from today's date.I also want to disable dates after 3 months.Is there any way to achieve this.

For example, today date is 30 oct.On showing datepicker instead of showing 30 oct it should show 31 Nov and I want to disable dates from Jan 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/3/)

The default date is 30 days from now and the end date is 90 days from now

```
var plus30days = new Date(),
    plus90days = new Date();

plus30days.setDate( plus30days.getDate() + 30 );
plus90days.setDate( plus90days.getDate() + 90 );

$( "#datepicker" )
    .datepicker( "setValue", plus30days )
    .on( "changeDate", function(ev) {
        if ( ev.date.valueOf() > plus90days.valueOf() ) {
            alert( "Hey-hey-hey! Wait a minute!" );
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setValue", plus30days );
        }

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "hide" );
    });
```